# configChanges not recognized by TabHost?

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-configchanges

I have a pretty big problem with my TabHost. Although I have declared all of my Activities (Including my TabHost Activity) to ignore orientation and keyboardHidden, if I flip my Phone (Android 4.0) It still recreates the activity.

Here is a shortened version of my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".TabHost"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity3"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

I don't think that the code of the activities would help?!
If it would however, let me know and I'll post it too.



Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are trying to stop the rotation of the screen use following code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for each activity.

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

**UPDATE**

According to API when using `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

**"orientation"**

The screen orientation has changed — the user has rotated the device. 
Note: **If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should also declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes when a device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.**

so, if you are targeting API level 13 or higher you gotta specify screen size also.

Comment: Well the screen should still be able rotate. But when it does it shouldn't restart/recreate the Activity itself.

Comment: UPDATE: Tested and this worked... Wow I'm always surprised again what dependencies are needed some time in the world of Android ;) Well thanks alot for helping!

Comment: glad it worked for you. You are right, google have bad reputation for keep changing and deprecating stuff

Comment: Unbelievable an arcane value needs to be inserted into an XML file for rotation of a common component to work appropriately.

Comment: I want my app to rotate when i change the orientation, simultaneously i don't want my activity to recreate. Is it possible ?